# Can I perform an action on all slice items at once in go?

Tags: multithreading, go, concurrency, goroutine

I have the following code:

```
func myfunction() {
    results := make([]SomeCustomStruct, 0)

    // ... results gets populated ...

    for index, value := range results {
        results[index].Body = cleanString(value.Body)
    }

    // ... when done, more things happen ...
}

func cleanString (in string) (out string) {
    s := sanitize.HTML(in)
    s = strings.Replace(s, "\n", " ", -1)
    out = strings.TrimSpace(s)
    return
}
```

The slice will never contain more than 100 or so entries. Is there any way I can exploit goroutines here to perform the cleanString function on each slice item at the same time rather than one by one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the slice only has 100 items or less and that's is the entirety of `cleanString`, you're not going to get a lot of speedup unless the body strings are fairly large.

Parallelizing it with goroutines would look something like:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
for index, value := range results {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(index int, body string) {
        defer wg.Done()
        results[index].Body = cleanString(body)
    }(index, value.Body)
}
wg.Wait()
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Yes I don't expect a huge boost but I'm interested in the principal too :)